# Declaring variables in PLSQL triggers in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am writing PLSQL trigger for MySQL database. I am trying to declare variables . So i am writing a declare block in the trigger. Here is my following code

```
CREATE TRIGGER leave_approve_trigger 
AFTER UPDATE ON leave_status
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE    //Syntax error
current_id integer;
BEGIN
if NEW.status == 'APPROVED'
THEN
select id into current_id from leave_request_table;
insert into update_table values(current_id);
ENDIF;
END;
```

The error I get is syntax error for mysql version 5.5.0. Can we actually declare variables. Thanks in advance

Comment: PL/SQL is the scripting language for the Oracle database.  It will not work with MySQL.  Here is a reference to the MySQL create trigger syntax:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in MySQL. Plus your code is invalid for PL/SQL as well, because the comparison operator is `=` not `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure syntax in a little different in MySQL, you must change some lines:

- Declare block must be after begin of code.
- the == operator but chanted to =
- ENDIF; must change to END IF;
- All block must begin with changing the delimiter for statements, and at the end restore it.
- If a field name is a reserved word it can be enclosed by ` to avoid syntax error.

Here is the code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER leave_approve_trigger 
AFTER UPDATE ON leave_status
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE current_id int;

    if NEW.`status` = 'APPROVED' THEN
        select id into current_id from leave_request_table;
        insert into update_table values(current_id);
    END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the MySQL version would be more like this:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER leave_approve_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON leave_status
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if NEW.status = 'APPROVED' THEN
        insert into update_table 
             select id
             from leave_request_table;
    END IF;
END;

delimiter ;
```

By the way, you don't need the variable in either Oracle or MySQL.  Just use `insert . . . select`.

I would think that you would also want to match to a specific row in the `leave_request_table`, but your trigger doesn't do that.